# Choose between Docusign price plans

Tags: docusignapi

I need to create an application where user could sign the document on my application without email sending, I want to know if this feature is provided by the `starter` price plan of the API ? or it is provided by which price plan

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a support site for Docusign. [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) The [Docusign website](https://www.docusign.com/) has a "Plans & Pricing" page, and if this does not address your concerns, it also has "Support" and "Contact Sales" links; please enquire there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you're referring to is `embedded signing`. My understanding is that it is included in all plans. But you'll need to confirm with DocuSign sales

Comment: This is not correct. Embedded signing is available for every plan, every account. The information you based your answer on is being updated. Please change the answer here, as I cannot post a new one.